# Mounted drives appearing twice in lists

Tags: 10.10, mount

I have mounted a couple of network shares with my `etc/fstab` file - it works great, just like it's supposed to, but unfortunately every mounted drive keeps appearing twice!

When clicking one of the duplicates, an error is shown; `Unable to mount: [mountname]. Mount: According to mtab, [mount address], is already mounted on [local mountpoint]. Mount failed`.

Here's how each mountpoint looks in my `etc/fstab`:

```
//192.168.1.2/backups /media/backups cifs defaults,user=myUserName,pass=myPassWord,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

What can I do to make sure that my mounted drives only are listed once?

Comment: I am getting all crazy about this - bounty is ON!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a know bug and I could not find a proper solution. Apparently the bug might be triggered by custom options on the fstab line.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/442130
and https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=597420

Answer (score 1):

(Further to what @user4124 said and their links) In you FSTAB lines make sure you do not use the `user` option as this is one of the triggers for the double-up.

Answer (score 0):

The work-around that fixed it for me was to put leave a blank line after each entry