# Partition showing up twice under devices

Tags: fstab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Mounted drives appearing twice in lists](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23033/mounted-drives-appearing-twice-in-lists)

I have an [NTFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS) data partition on the same drive as my Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) partition. I wanted to have this partition automatically mount at startup so that [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) can start synchronising at startup without me having to manually mount it (my Dropbox folder is on the partition). I edited the [fstab](http://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab) file by appending the following to it:

```
#Data-Partition
UUID=762639DE416D0A21 /media/Data ntfs-3g rw,auto,users,exec,nls=utf8,umask=003,gid=46,uid=1000    0   2
```

The drive now automounts at startup like I wanted, but now I have a duplicate **Data** entry under my **Devices** list. This only appeared after editing the fstab file.

[image: Image showing the problem]

The second Data entry under Devices does not mount properly, and I do not want it there.
**Why is this duplicate entry there, and how can I get rid of it?**

## Additional information:

Here is the output I get from `cat /proc/partitions`:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0  976762584 sda
   8        1     102400 sda1
   8        2  111574016 sda2
   8        3  803643392 sda3
   8        4          1 sda4
   8        5   55410688 sda5
   8        6    6028288 sda6
  11        0    1048575 sr0
```

Comment: could you paste the output of the command: cat /proc/partitions

Comment: @tomodachi I added output from `cat /proc/partitions` to the question.

Comment: Change fstab to mount by label instead of UUID, this is a bug reported on Launchpad already. I'm sorry I can't post a link right now but try searching for the duplicate here.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=launchpad+bug+partitions+twice

Comment: @TomBrossman Excellent, that fixed the problem. I'll be sure to check Launchpad first for future problems first (I'm relatively new to linux). Thanks.

Comment: Is this question a duplicate on askubuntu? If not, I'd be happy to accept your comment as an answer if you make it one. If it is, I can delete this question.

Comment: I found the duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/23033/69759